# TSP with "enemy" nodes

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, graph-algorithms, co.combinatorics, optimization

I am curious if the following variation of the traveling salesman problem (TSP) (or a vehicle routing problem (VRP) version) occurs in the literature and has a name I could search for.
The story/idea is we have *ally* locations and *enemy* locations. We want to visit all allies while encountering few enemies. I thought of this when reading some papers in combinatorial optimization, but this is not my area of expertise. So, I don't know if I am searching the correct words.

The graph theoretic formulation is that we have an edge weighted graph $G = (V,E)$ which is bicolored so $V = A \cup B$ (note the coloring need not be proper, i.e. $G$ doesn't have to be bipartite). We are given an integer $k$ and want to find a minimum weight cycle (or alternatively path) which contains all vertices in $A$ and at most $k$ vertices in $B$.

Has this problem been studied somewhere? Does it have a name or fit inside a known generalized TSP? Or maybe there is some reduction to known version of TSP?

When $k=0$ we can delete vertices in $B$ along with all edges incident to them and we have the usual TSP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As TSP is an optimization problem, there are not many variants of it (that I know of) that add hard constraints to the formulation. But if I have understood correctly, your problem is a special case of (a variant of) the Prize-Collecting Travelling Salesman Problem (PCTSP), which seems to be introduced in [1] *(NB: Technical report, written on typewriter. Hard to read)*:

Given a graph $G$ and a *prize* $w_v$ and a *penalty* $p_v$ for each vertex $v \in G$, you are asked to construct a tour that minimizes the cost of travelling, plus the penalty for every vertex you do *not* visit. In addition, you have the constraint that the combined prize for every vertex you *do* visit must be higher than some prescribed sum $W$.

If you are allowed to put negative values on your prizes, your problem can be formulated as a PCTSP this way:

- Let $p_v = 0$ for every $v\in V$
- Let $w_a = n$ for every $a\in A$
- Let $w_b = -1$ for every $b\in B$
- Let $W = n\cdot |A| - k$

It's worth it to add that having shorter routes often will lead to cheaper tours anyway. For example, if $G$ is metric, then you can just solve TSP on $G[A]$, as visiting any vertices in $B$ will be considered a detour.

[1] *Balas, Egon*, [**The prize collecting traveling salesman problem**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/net.3230190602), Networks 19, No. 6, 621-636 (1989). [ZBL0676.90089](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0676.90089).